# How does the Remove All Members from Opportunity Team works?

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-teams

I want to know how the Salesforce standard functionality of removing all the team members from an opportunity record works? I want to implement the same action on a custom object. Is it a button, link or a quick action? Does it call a JS file or an apex class?

Comment: You have to build your own.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above. There are some functions that are just built into the UI. This function is one such case. You'll have to write your own custom logic.